# this.moment.hours() is not a function error when changing the hours of a Moment variable

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I am working on a simple modal that is used to create an event, this event has a startDate and an endDate. In the modal I'm using a mat-form-field with seperate time- and datepickers that I want to combine into a Moment when saving the form.

Both the dates are in the `Moment` format, and are bound to the datepickers with an `NgModel`, and I made `startTime` and `endTime` Date variables that are bound to the timepicker using `NgModel`.

The picking of both the times and dates is fine, I can log the times and dates after they have been picked and they return the correct values.

This is my .ts class, I left out some parts that are not relevant to the question:

```
export class CreateOrEditEventComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
    startTime: Date = new Date();
    endTime: Date = new Date();

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _eventService: EventServiceProxy,
        private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateOrEditEventComponent>
    ) {
        super(injector);
        // Initialize the dates here because to make sure they are not undefined...
        this.event.startDate = moment();
        this.event.endDate = moment();
    }

    save() {
    // create the event
            this.event.startDate.hours(this.startTime.getHours()).minutes(this.startTime.getMinutes());
            this.event.endDate.hours(this.endTime.getHours()).minutes(this.endTime.getMinutes());

            this._eventService.create(this.event).subscribe(result => {
                this.notify.success('Event is made!');
            });
        }
    }
```

When trying to add the variables from the timepicker to their respective `startDate` and `endDate` variables, I get this error:

```
this.event.startDate.hours is not a function at 
CreateOrEditEventComponent.push../src/app/events/create-or-edit- 
event/create-or-edit-event.component.ts.CreateOrEditEventComponent.save
```

This gets thrown at the line in the `save()` method where I want to combine the hours and minutes from the timepicker variable with the dates from the `Event` object that im gonna create.

I have tried to make the variables used for the timepicker `Moments` too, but I got the same errors when trying to retrieve the hours and minutes from these. So I have switched them out for Dates for the time being. This can't be done with the `this.event` date variables, since it expects these to be `Moments`

Comment: How are you calling `save`? Seems likely the problem is there. What do you see when you set a breakpoint on the line where the error occurs and, when the breakpoint is hit, you examine `this`, `this.event`, and `this.event.startDate`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The `save()` method is the `(ngSubmit)` property on the form. 

The `this` is the `CreateOrEditEventComponent` itself, the `this.event` holds the `this.event.startDate` and `this.event.endDate` variables like it should. These variables display the proper date: `endDate: Tue May 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`.




The `this.startTime` and `this.endTime` variables hold the current date(because i initialized them), and the time I have set in the timepickers: `startTime: Sat May 25 2019 15:26:32 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`.

Comment: You're double-checking that paused on a breakpoint? Is `this.event.startDate` actually a Moment instance at that point? (I'd find it odd if your debugger showed you `Tue May 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` or similar if it were a Moment instance.)  It sounds like somewhere (not in the code above) you've accidentally assigned a `Date` to `startDate` rather than a `moment` (though I'd think TypeScript would flag that up, unless `this.event.startDate` is declared as type `any`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only declare the `this.event` dates in the constructor as a `moment()`, I don't manually use them anywhere else in the class except for the lines that throw the error. If I mouse-over the this.event date variables in Visual Studio it shows that they are `Moments` too.

Perhaps this has something to do with the `ngModels` in the Datepickers returning wrong values?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that, when stopped on a **breakpoint**, you can inspect `this.event.startDate` and see that it's a Moment object, but then when you press the Step Over button, you get the error that `this.event.startDate.hour` is not a function.

Comment: You are right, i overlooked the proto attributes in the debugger and it is indeed a Date object: `endTime: Fri May 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Date()
getDate: ƒ getDate()`

Comment: We know `endTime` is a `Date`. It's `startDate` and `endDate` that should be Moments, not `startTime` and `endTime` (from the code above).

Comment: Oh right sorry, I was indeed looking at the wrong variables. I checked the `this.event.startDate` and `this.event.endDate` and they are `Date()` objects instead of Moments

Comment: So that's the problem. :-) Now you just have to find out why they're `Date` instead of `Moment`, but that's why you're getting the error you're getting.

Comment: Yea exactly, thanks for the help!